# I need a regex command that isolates all numbers not adjacent to a caret (^)

Tags: java, regex, string

I am having a lot of trouble figuring Regex command out, and can't seem to find the right combination to fit what I want

Example:

Input: `1x^3+5x^2+6x+2`

Output: `1 5 6 2`

I need to isolate those values, as they are the coefficients of my polynomial. The input is a String so I figured the best way to do this was by using the `.split()` function with a custom Regex command.

Comment: "*I figured the best way to do this was by using the .split()*" that could be nice idea. What is stopping you from using it?

Comment: Have you considered **parsing** it instead of applying a regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regular expression:

```
(?<!\^)\d+(?!\^)
```

This uses a negative lookahead and lookbehind to remove characters next to ^.

Since you want to extract coefficients, it finds one or more digits. Modified the middle part if needed.

You can use it this way in Java, for example:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\^)\\d+(?!\\^)").matcher("1x^3+5x^2+6x+2");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Coefficient: " + m.group());
}
```

EDIT:

If you also want to detect negative coefficients, you can check for an optional - before digits:

```
(?<!\^)-?\d+(?!\^)
```

Keep in mind that as you try to capture more complicated patterns, regular expressions become less suitable as you may get lost in a number of cases to cover.

Comment: Hey I used it in the `.replaceAll()` function to no avail. Any ideas why? Code looks like this: `function.replaceAll("!(?<!\\^)[^\\^+x](?!\\^)", " ");`

Comment: @JacksonHaile Added a Java example.

Comment: Any idea how to also include the negatives?